# How to trigger a process from another process in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, process, ipc

I'm developing a C application on Linux. 
To make things clear, I translated my problem into two simple programs:

- Prog1: creates a file and runs an infinite loop to read from it
- Prog2: writes the word "Hello" into the file 10 times

Whenever the word is written into the file, the infinite loop in Prog1 detects it and simply reads it. (Both codes are mentioned at the end).

The problem is: Prog1 actually tries to read the word then sleeps for 1 second before trying to read again. I want Prog1 to read the word "Hello" as soon as it is written in the file (real time) and if possible, I would like to get rid of the infinite while loop in Prog1.

Is there any professional solution for this problem? like a special high priority interrupt to trigger Prog1 from Prog2?

Thanks.

```
/* Prog1 */
#define FIFO_FILE "MYFIFO"
int main (void)
{
    int fd;
    int read_bytes;
    char buf[6];

    mknod(FIFO_FILE, S_IFIFO|0640,0);

    while(1)
    {
        fd = open(FIFO_FILE, O_RDONLY);

        read_bytes = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
        if(read_bytes == 0)
            break;

        buf[read_bytes] = '\0';

        printf("Received string is : %s \n", buf);

        sleep(1);
    }

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}

/* Prog2 */
#define FIFO_FILE "MYFIFO"
int main (void)
{
    int fd;
    int stringlen;
    int count = 0;
    char buf[6]={'H','e','l','l','o'};

    fd = open(FIFO_FILE, O_CREAT|O_WRONLY);

    while(count <= 10)
    {   
        stringlen = strlen(buf);
        buf[stringlen] = '\0';

        write(fd, buf, strlen(buf));
        printf("Sent String \n");

        count++;

        sleep(1);

    }

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think [pipes](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) or named pipes are better suited for this purpose, or even sockets. You could use them in conjunction with [select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) or [poll](https://linux.die.net/man/3/poll) functions.

Comment: You could send a signal which wakes the other process. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What tyou try to do is what the command [`tail -f`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tail) do.  You can look over [its source code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c) to see the professional solution.

On the other hand, you should not use sleep, but `poll` from the socket library.

Comment: side-note: GNU tail is using inotify instead of poll if available

Comment: @hek2mgl If `inotify` is disabled, I think it uses `poll` instead. As I see here https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/, this works only when `read` is passed a file system descriptor -- not any kind of file descriptor accepts this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will take my time to investigate it in more details. However, it seems that this command only deals with files. What if Prog2 writes the message "Hello" in a shared memory instead of a file? How can I trigger Prog1 once the word is written on memory?

Comment: @Kalkhouri correct. after you follow a tutorial about poll you can read a professional implementation of tail and after that you can read how poll is implemented inside the kernel and implement your own version of poll to understand the details of tail.